# Nginx Reverse proxy config

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm having issues with getting a simple config to work with nginx. I have a server that host docker containers so nginx is in a container. So lets call the url `foo.com`. I would like for the url `foo.com/service1` to actually just go to foo.com on another port, so it would actually be pulling `foo.com:4321` and `foo.com/service2` to be pulling `foo.com:5432` and so on. Here is the config I have been having issues with.

```
http {
    server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;

        location /service1/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:4321/;
        }

        location /service2/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:5432/;
        }

    }
}
```

So the services and nginx live at 192.168.0.2. What is the prefered way to be able to do this? Thank you in advance!

As A side note, this is running in a docker container. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access `http://192.168.0.2:4321/` and `http://192.168.0.2:5432/` on the host server?

Comment: Yes, I can curl the two listed addresses and ports from the machine running nginx and I can also open the pages from my local machine on those ports without issue.

Comment: Are you able to get response inside your nginx container by: curl `http://192.168.0.2:4321/` and `http://192.168.0.2:5432/`?

Comment: I think that the OP creates low-quality questions and disappears. Time passes by, people answer or ask for more details. For no avail, they simply waste their time. Is there a flag to close such kind of questions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check whether your `foo.com` is pointing to the right ip address or not first by removing the reverse proxy config. E.g.

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.com;

        location / {
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if your `ip` address already has a service running on port 80 you should specify the `server_name` for each service like in my example. Nginx can only distinguish which service to respond to which domain by `server_name`.

*My guess is that you forgot the `server_name` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.com;

        location /service1/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:4321/;
        }

        location /service2/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:5432/;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is almost identical to what I have. I still get the same results as what I posted, 504 gateway timeout

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess your problem is not related to Nginx per se, but instead it is related to Docker networking. You provided insufficient information to make a detailed conclusion, but here it is a couple of suggestions:

1. run a simple Docker container at the same host where nginx container is running and try `curl` from inside that container (I've seen your answer that you are able to call `curl` from the server running Nginx, but it's not really the same)
2. for example, if the server running nginx container is OSX or Windows, it may use an intermediate Linux virtual machine with its own network stack, IP addreses, routing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is my conf sending to inner glassfish. Check out the use of proxy_redirect off & proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

```
    #Glassfish
    location /MyService/   {

            index index.html;

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:18000/MyService/;

    }
```