# Hosting site on different containers on same docker host

Tags: linux, docker, apache

I am trying to setup multiple containers listening on different ports hosting sites.

Example:

```
example1.com 8080 -> 80 container1 (apache)
example2.com 8081 -> 80 container2 (apache)
```

What is the correct way to do it?

I have tried http redirects/rewrites (inside containers) but cannot get it to work..

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse proxy on the server. I'd go with `nginx` and configure it [similar to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452101/nginx-reverse-proxy-config) to forward traffic to `example1.com` to its own port `8080`. In Apache this can be done as well. It's called [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)